# FlatList only updates after user interaction occurs

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-props

I have a component that gets data from navigation props which I use to set the state in CDM():

```
this.setState({
  data: this.props.navigation.getParam('data', 'Some Data')
})
```

The state is then used in a FlatList. **When props change.. the FlatList doesn't update... Until the client touches the screen.**

I have tried putting the props directly into the FlatList:

```
data={this.props.navigation.getParam('data', 'Some Data')}
```

I have tried using the extraData prop:

```
<FlatList
   style={{ flexGrow: 1, marginTop: 10 }}
   data={this.state.data}
   keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
   extraData={this.props.navigation.getParam('data', 'Some Data')}
   renderItem={({ item }) => {...}>
```

I have tried using componentDidUpdate() to reset state when the props change but CDU never gets called.

**EDIT:** 
I have a feeling it is because when I add items; I'm navigating back (navigation.goBack())
and goBack() dosnt refresh the state? i'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/922#issuecomment-344752635

It's essentially passing a function as a parameter and calling that function to change the state of the parent then calling goBack()